# useState not setting inital state with a filtered array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

I am pulling data using `useContext` into my component. I then want to filter `tasks` so it only shows the relevant tasks for the project.

I am filtering `tasks` into `initState` and then want to set the inital state using useState of this filtered list.

When I filter the list in `initState` I am getting the correct values however when I do this:

`const [listToRender, setListToRender] = useState(initState)`

`listToRender` is an empty array and there is no state within the component.

```
    const TasksTable = ({ match: { params: { projectId }} }) => {
    const { tasks } = useContext(TasksContext)
    const initState = [...tasks].filter(task => task.taskProject === projectId)
    const [listToRender, setListToRender] = useState(initState)
```

[image]

Does anyone know where I could be going wrong here?

Here is a console.log of the different values when the component first renders

[image]

Comment: if sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a useEffect to init the value of the listToRender state

```
 const TasksTable = ({ match: { params: { projectId }} }) => {
 const { tasks } = useContext(TasksContext)
 const [listToRender, setListToRender] = useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
const initState = tasks?.filter(task => task.taskProject === projectId) ?? []
 setListToRender(initState)
}, [tasks, projectId]);
```

The reason is, that it may not have the task data when it's setting the listToRender state, leading it to be an empty array.

A useEffect will run every time the component gets an update, in this case, the useEffect will only run if the tasks changes, ( see the dependency array ). Therefore, when the tasks get a value, it will trigger the useEffect to update the listToRender state.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. Do you mind helping me understand why this works? Why would this work in a `useEffect` that runs when the component loads but doesn't work outside of it?

Comment: And you don't need to copy `tasks` by `[...tasks]` because the method `filter` returns a new array.

Comment: A useEffect will run every time the component gets an update, in this case, the useEffect will only run if the tasks changes, ( see  the dependency array ). Therefore, when the tasks get a value, it will trigger the useEffect to update the listToRender state. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to update `listToRender` in the future by `setListToRender()`? if you're not then you can use `useMemo` instead:

```
const TasksTable = ({ match: { params: { projectId }} }) => {
  const { tasks } = useContext(TasksContext);
  
  const initState = useMemo(() => {
    return tasks.filter(task => task.taskProject === projectId);
  }, [projectId, tasks]);
```

Comment: Yeah I will want to update `listToRender` at a later date based on additional filters that the user selects - thanks for that!